# How to write a custom validator the uses external data Angular 5

Tags: angular, validation, typescript

I'm trying to write a custom validator in which I check whether the value typed in a field is higher/lower than the property of an external object. This is my code:

```
// defining the user property in the constructor
this.user        = this.authGuard.currentUser();

// This is my FromGroup defined in my init function
this.firstFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  budget: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(10), this.validateBudget]],
  start_date: ['', Validators.required],
  end_date: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Then my validator function would work like this:

```
validateBudget(c: FormControl) {
const credits = this.user.credits / 100;
let valid = false;

if (credits <  this.secondFormGroup.getRawValue().budget) {
  valid = false;
} else {
  valid = true;
}

return {
  validateBudget: {
    valid: false
  }
};
```

}

However the above is not working. I get the errors: Cannot read property user of undefined. Cannot read property get of undefined and a myriad of other errors. How could I go about writing this validator so I can check what the user is typing in the budget field against what the user (this.user) has on the credits property?

Comment: in your example, what is `this.secondFormGroup` supposed to be?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo the whole form with all fields (including budget)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass in a function (validator) to be executed later, but when it's executed the context of `this` is lost. To keep `this` as in this component that holds the form, use either fat arrow function:

```
budget: ['', /* */, (c: FormControl) => this.validateBudget(c)]],
```

Or `bind`:

```
budget: ['', /* */, this.validateBudget.bind(this)]],
```